# Excel 2010 - ActiveX controls

Tags: excel, vba, controls, activex

I've been having this problem for two or three weeks now.

Any file I create with ActiveX controls that must run a code for example clicking on a button, will work fine on my computer, but on any other computers will not work.

If you save the file, from other computer, it will show a Unexpecter error 32809 and after you close the file and reopen it, the controls will work.

Note that this happens for every file I save from my computer. Even if I get a working macro, I open it and save it with no changes, on other computers will not work.
I deleted many times *.exd files as a suggest from Internet, but still no good.

Can anyone help me with this problem, please ?
Thank you

Comment: There are a *lot* of existing posts about this error, you need to google them first before you ask for help.  Type "activex error 32809" in the search box.   You can't possibly miss the ones that talk about the trouble caused by the December 2014 security update.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this error seems a bit different. ActiveX controls aren't disabled, they are enabled on my computer and on client's computer, but when he changes for example a combo box, the code for that combobox_change doesn't run, but on my computer, it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Do a wildcard search for `exd` files (search for `*.exd`) and make sure you are not searching for **exe!**. Delete all the `exd` files returned from the search. That will do it.

Comment: I searched for *.exd files, I'm pretty sure I didn't delete all my .exe files.

Comment: I used this  DEL /S /A:H /A:-H *.EXD

Comment: did you restart Excel after you deleted all the .exd files?

Comment: Excel was closed during deleteing .exd files. Every Office App was closed.

Comment: I have not used DOS commands in ages :). So I can't verify if your command has deleted all the .exd files. Why don't you try searching for exd files on all your local drives using Windows explorer and then manually delete all the exd files.

Comment: hmm, sorry I am out of ideas. That really should have worked for you. I have had success with it on a dozen of systems.

Comment: http://www.fileshare.ro/e31331408

here's the link of a file i saved from my computer. it's really simple, when you click the button a messagebox will appear, but can you tell me if it works on your computer ?

Comment: have you test it, please?